How can I put the django admin filters at the top instead of at the right sidebar?
Filters are placed by default at the right sidebar in django admin. If there are lots of filters with lots of values, it is not very convenient for user to scroll down. Therefore, I would like to have a way to place them at the top instead.
I created a change_list.html template in the project level. Struggling with css

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
